# How do I check which process is using port 1099?

Tags: networking, process, port

From my java application, it gives me an error like this:
[image]

I am using Windows XP. Could anyone give me any recommendations as how to figure out which process is using port 1099? My firewall is off and I don't have any antivirus programs that can be messing it up.

Thank you.  It is very much appreciated.

Edit: From the suggestions below, do any of you have any ideas how to kill this process listening at port 1099?
[image]

Comment: FYI: 1099 is used for Java RMI so the process in question will almost certainly be java.exe or a java based app like eclipse.exe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the output for `netstat -a -n -b` should show you all connections and what application is using those ports.

Update Response:
You can hit `ctrl-shift-esc` which brings up the windows task manager.  Click on the processes tab and then go to `View->Select Columns` make sure PID is selected and hit OK. Then make sure the checkbox for `Show processes from all users` is selected. Then you can sort by that column and should be able to find your PID easily and you can always right click the process in question and select `End Process` or `End Process Tree`.

Just make sure you know what you are killing and that it isn't critical.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Please see above for updated question. Thank you again.

Comment: +1; You could also type `tasklist | findstr <pid-here>`, so you don't have to leave the command line.

Answer (score 2):

netstat /ano will give you the PID of the process that is using each port.

Just for the sake of completeness as well, you can kill tasks from the command line via PID as well using the taskkill command.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Please see above for updated question. Thanks again.